# Manually translating code from one language to another

Tags: c, matlab, programming-languages, fortran

I often write codes in MATLAB/Python to test whether my algorithm is feasible (& actually works). I then need to convert the entire code into C and sometimes, in FORTRAN90.

**What would be a good way to manually convert a medium sized code from one language to another?**

I have tried :

- Converting the entire code from one into another and then testing it.
  (Sometimes, there are errors and bugs which just won't go away and the finding the source of the error becomes a problem)
- Go line by line and check for consistency of outputs every few lines.
  (Too time consuming)
- Use converters like `f2c`.
  (In my experience, they are extremely horrible. I link to a lot of libraries which have different function calls for C and Fortran)

Also,:

- I am fairly conversant with the programming languages I deal with so I don't need manuals or reference guides for my work (i.e. I know the syntax).
- I am not asking this question specifically about MATLAB and C but rather as a translation paradigm.
- Regarding the size, the codes are less than 100 lines long.
- I dont want to call the code of one language to another. Please don't suggest that.

Comment: The first option seems the most logical. Conversion and testing. But the conversion needs to happen step by step interlaced with unit tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different languages call for different paradigms. You *definitely* don't write and design code the same way in eg. Matlab, Python, C# or C++. Even object hierarchies will change a lot depending on the language.

That said, if your code consists in a few interconnected procedures, then you may go away with a direct line by line translation (every language allow you to write two or three interconnected functions while remaining idiomatic). But this is the case only for the simplest programs.

Prototyping in a high level language and then implementing the same idea in a robust and clean way in a "production" language is a very good practice, but involves two very different things :

1. Prototype in whatever language you want. Test, experiment, and convince yourself that the idea works. Pay attention to the big picture, don't focus on performance but on the high level ideas. Pay also attention to difficulties that you encounter when implementing, as you'll face them again in step 2.
2. Implement from scratch the idea in the production environment in language X. It will be quicker than if you did not do the prototyping stage, since most of the difficulties have been met in stage 1. Use idiomatic X, and focus on correctness. Pay attention to corner cases, general robustness, and once it works correctly, performance. You'll notice that roughly half of your code is made of new things which did not appear in 1. (eg. error checking, corner case handling, input/output, unit testing, etc).

You can see that line by line translation is obviously *not* a good idea, since you don't translate into the same program.

Also, when not prototyping, I find myself throwing away the first version and making another one that I like better, ie. I find myself prototyping ! Implementing the same thing twice is not a loss of time, it is normal development flow.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using a higher level domain specific language with multiple backends (e.g., Matlab, C, Fortran), producing clean and idiomatic code for each target language, probably with some optimisations. If your problem domain is narrow and every piece of code is more or less typical, it should be fairly trivial to design and implement such a DSL.

Comment: And if it doesn't exist, roll your own. It has not to be perfect from the start. But I'd rather spend some hours or even a weekend on it than only a single hour manually translating code. Remember, with 10% effort, you get 90% of the solution.

Comment: @Ingo, of course I meant a bespoke homegrown DSL. There won't be any ready to use one tailored specifically for your needs.

Comment: Most probably not, you're right. OTOH, you never know nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Break the source down into psuedo-code with input/process/output and then write your new code base to fit that spec.